# Linphone on Windows Server 2012, with multiple users

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, voip, sip

Im going to explain everything first. We have Windows server 2012, where our users are connecting to (lets say around 60-70 per server). After Linphohe installation and first start of the application (in task manager I can see, that every user has his own instance), under every users appdata Linphone folder with settings is created. So far so good. BUT when i try to change SIP/UDP port in settings to something else than 5060 (to give every user his own port), it seems to connect to SIP server, but my calls are timed out.

I can provide Linphone logs, if it could help.

What are the factors from networking point of view (ports, SIP etc.) which could be causing this. Probably Im the one who is doing something wrong, but networking isn't really my field of expertise, but I want to improve. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thi is, infamously, a problem with *linphone*, not with networking. You should read here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25154905/2796243

Comment: I would switch to another softphone.